Request timeout while trying to read NSE pre open market website with Python Requests
I am trying to read NSE India website but request gets timeout. I have the code below:
import requests

url = 'https://www.nseindia.com/market-data/pre-open-market-cm-and-emerge-market'

response = requests.get(url, headers={"Content-Type":"text"})

print(response.text)

The error I get:
 File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 440, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1349, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 316, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 277, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/socket.py", line 704, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1241, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1099, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 755, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 531, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 735, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 447, in _make_request
    self._raise_timeout(err=e, url=url, timeout_value=read_timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 353, in _raise_timeout

What is missing? I am running this on MAC OS

Your error trace stack is not complete. In your question you are saying request time but in trace stack there no Request time error. Please add full trace stack.


I would suggest try to respect robots.txt whenever scrapping.
Here is working solution. You can add some extra headers to act like browser.

import requests

url_base = 'https://www.nseindia.com/market-data/pre-open-market-cm-and-emerge-market'


request_headers = {
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/124.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

res = requests.request('get', url_base, headers=request_headers)

print(res.status_code) # returns 200



web servers sometime dont like requests coming from origins like scripts/code etc. In this case adding User-Agent worked but might be different for different site.


Please explain more about "respect robots.txt". Also, it's not scrapping. That's something completely different

From my point of you are trying to read content from NSE India website. There is a reason you are facing request timeout because the website is not letting you read it's pages. Here, on this reddit post tells why you are unable to request the website.
This answer is from one of reddit post if you are wondering why it was happening.
Reddit Link

You have to understand, the web is attempting to defend itself from you. Whether or not that's your intent, you're technically a malicious actor. Websites don't want to be scraped - they're saying so, in robots.txt, which you probably didn't even look at - and you're attempting to scrape them anyway. So, you're experiencing the results of web sites defending themselves by using various tricks to stop you, including hanging the connection so your script stalls. They're banking on you not knowing the requests library well enough to set a timeout on your own end, and so far they've been right.

Presumming you are reading content of your given website. What you are missing is User-Agent in your header.
So your code will look more like this:
import requests

url = 'https://www.nseindia.com/market-data/pre-open-market-cm-and-emerge-market'

header = {
  "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/125.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}
get_response = requests.get(url, headers=header)
print(get_response.status_code)
print(get_response.text)

